# How to create a file from buffer with javascript?

Tags: javascript, blob

My api return a string like that:

```
%PDF-1.4
%����
1 0 obj
<</Creator (Chromium)
/Producer (Skia/PDF m71)
/CreationDate (D:20181106140055+00'00')
/ModDate (D:20181106140055+00'00')>>
endobj
2 0 obj
<</Filter /FlateDecode
/Length 1728>> stream
x��ZY�#7~����@����gg���$م��������R�=n_�����:����<ʺB�
��t��QŔ��?�����s�SQ&ư���J����_��X�����8O���0�~}]��_w�^���?Ҝ�[���}�)�̢�Q�X��z)&/)8T�R@I!�����d%  ��>!&(�c�'=�K�zb"�&��+� �3��h���W���"Ĉ��5й�n0
:�-�R4C&.����2  ����,)�/4Iq�\���؊���b���D��h��o�xh&FLLl�#@31b�b
"�Xt�s��
-c�<�
�7V��3�۷�p_�nt�(���3�>�M�2�Bws�䈅���!��:)N�4��.RH��B��
!Ni,B()�(�E�,���!m���K��� W�)X.kY� �D"9�Ds�\�s�� u�G�m3ȓ�����
```

It's created a buffer in my node api and it sent to my front app (vuejs).
I've tried to do that (in my front app ):

```
var link = document.createElement("a");
link.setAttribute("target","_blank");
if(Blob !== undefined) {
  var blob = new Blob([res.data],{type:"application/pdf;charset=utf-8;"});
  link.setAttribute("href", URL.createObjectURL(blob));
} else {                         
  link.setAttribute("href","data:application/pdf," + 
  encodeURIComponent(res.data));
}
link.setAttribute("download",'filename.pdf');
document.body.appendChild(link);
link.click();
document.body.removeChild(link);
```

but I got a blank pdf file.

My api's headers:

```
let buffer = await avaliacaoPDF.gerarPDFAvaliacao(register);        
res.status(200).header('Content-type', 'application/pdf').send(buffer);
```

What can I do to create this file?

Comment: Have you considered converting your buffer to base64 before serving it?

Comment: Thanks a lot man, I followed your advice and I got it!!! Thank so much!!!!!